# How to import nodes with custom fields using Feeds module and Feeds JSONPath Parser

Tags: 7, feeds

I've got a content type called 2Wd-Tractor with this structure :

- Model (node title)
- Engine
- Transmission
- Operational
- Hydraulic System

Engine field is a custom field implemented using Field Api and it does have these subfields :

- Make
- Model
- Net Power
- PTO Power
- Aspiration
- Power Measured At
- and ...

After that to make this field visible in feeds mapping hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter was implemented.

Here is the code :

```
foreach (field_info_instances($entity_type, $bundle_name) as $name => $instance)
{
    $info = field_info_field($name);
    unset($callback);

    if ($info['type']=='uceen2wdtractor')
    {
        //The callback for this field type goes here.
        $callback = 'TARGET_SETTER_FOR_en2wdtractor';
    }

    if (isset($callback))
    {
        $targets[$name] =array(
            'name'=>check_plain($instance['label']),
            'callback' => $callback,
            'description' => t('The @label field of the node.', array('@label' => $instance['label'])),
        );
    }
}
```

Data is imported to Feeds using json files , An importer is provided with these settings :

---

[image]
[image]
[image]

finally this is my json file :

[image]

The Problem is no data is stored in Engine field . this is the dsm($node) in hook_node_presave :

[image]

Comment: Does your field save ok when creating a node via the UI?

Comment: @littledynamo yes it does , it is even saved when creating nodes via services module and json application format

Comment: Can you post your hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter?

Comment: @littledynamo attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 places where the problem could lie:

1. Data not being correctly parsed by feeds
2. Data not being correctly saved by feeds
3. Problem with the field definition itself

Number 3 is ruled out since fields save correctly via the UI.

**Troubleshooting Number 1.**

Add a `hook_feeds_after_parse` to your module and either step through with a debugger or dump the `$items` array to the `dblog`:

```
function mymodule_feeds_after_parse(FeedsSource $source, FeedsParserResult $result) {
  if($source->id == 'ENTER YOUR SOURCE ID HERE') {
    watchdog('My Module', '<pre>' . print_r($result->items, TRUE) . '</pre>');
  }
}
```

Question: is there a value in the items array for your engine field?

If no: there is a problem in the JSON parser definitions and feeds is not extracting the data correctly.

If yes: if the information exists that you require, i.e. every sub field value exists then the problem is not with the feeds parsing.

**Troubleshooting Number 2**

This points to an issue with your implementation of `hook_feeds_processor_targets_alter`.  Most likely, the data is not in the correct format for saving.  Add some watchdog statements in this function to determine:

1. Is the callback being fired?
2. If the callback is being fired then there is an issue with your [hook_feeds_set_target](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!feeds!feeds.api.php/function/my_module_set_target/7) implementation.  It isn't providing the correct data format to allow the field to be saved.  You could add a `dpm()` statement to `hook_node_update` and then save a node via the UI. This will show the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

For troubleshooting data that is not correctly parsed, you can also use the [Feeds Import Preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/feedspreview) module. This module allows you to see what your source looks like after it has been parsed.